# Angular 6 | Data is empty when posting a file

Tags: angular, laravel, file-upload, angular6, laravel-5.6

Using Laravel 5.6 as backend and Angular 6 as frontend
I want to upload a file but its not happening
I am getting the `formData` as empty in laravel controller.
The `console.log` is working it shows this

```
File(674)
```

This is my function which calls laravel.

```
signup(input: any, fileToUpload: File) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let apiURL = `${this.signupApi}`;        
    let formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload);
    console.log(fileToUpload);
    this.httpClient.post(apiURL, { input, formData })
        .toPromise()
        .then(
        res => { // Success 

            if (res['code'] == 'taken') {
                resolve('taken');
            } else if (res['code'] !== 500) {
                resolve(true);
            } else {
                // return false to indicate fail
                resolve(false);
            }
        },
        msg => { // Error
            reject(msg);
        });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

This is the function which calls the service function

```
fileToUpload: File = null;
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
}
this.signupCharityService.signup(this.input, this.fileToUpload).then(data => {
        if (data == 'taken') {                    
            this.haveTaken = true;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.haveTaken = false;
            }, 3000);
        } else if (data == true) {
            this.flashMessagesService.show('Signup Success. Check your email for activation link.', { cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 5000 });                    
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
        } else {
            this.haveError = true;
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.haveError = false;
            }, 3000);
        }
    })
```

The HTML

```
<div class="file-ulload-outer">
        <div class="custom-file-upload">
            <input data-type="file-upload" type="file" class="form-control" (change) = "handleFileInput($event.target.files)" (keypress) = "onChange()"/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I think it's something to do with FormData i don't know.

Comment: can you share your form code

Comment: @Chellappan what code you are asking about?

Comment: this is service file where is your component.ts code where you have initialised the formControl for form

Comment: @Chellappan see now

Comment: which approach are you using template driven or reactive?

Comment: @Chellappan Reactive

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177277/discussion-between-chellappan-and-prit-patel).

Answer (score 0):

I don't why it was causing problem but when i sent just formData without input with it, it worked. Like this `.post(apiURL, formData)`